# Transparency not retained Mathematica 3ds Export

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, export, opacity

I have a semi transparent 3d model that I have created in Mathematica and exported to 3ds, and obj file formats. Once I open the 3ds, obj files with blender or GLC Player, the models are not transparent any more and I cannot see through them. Do I need to set some extra flags to `Export` to tell mathematica to retain transparency in color information ?

Comment: AFAIK `Export` does not support `Opacity` directives for 3ds and OBJ.

Comment: For which extension it supports opacity ?

Comment: If the alpha/transparency is on the whole object, could you not just import the obj file into say blender and edit the alpha/transparency of the material on the object to make it transparent again?

Comment: But to answer your question Neel, the only 3d format that I know that **may** take into account the opacity is the POV ray script format in its 'pigment' setting.

Comment: You could try DXF export with colors. Colors should be fairly easy to use as distinguishing elements on which opacity can be applied in your software.